# How to add rules in .htaccess via WordPress function

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, wordpress

I am trying to add rules in .htaccess via WordPress function which works perfect but always need to update permalink structure to get it added in .htaccess. How can I refresh / reload .htaccess automatically so that new rules can be added without updating permalink structure.

```
function add_to_htaccess( $rules ) {

$content = <<<EOD
\nAddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/plain
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/html
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE text/css
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/xhtml+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/rss+xml
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-javascript
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-php
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE application/x-httpd-fastphp
AddOutputFilterByType DEFLATE image/svg+xml
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE\n\n
EOD;
    return $content . $rules;

}
add_filter('mod_rewrite_rules', 'add_to_htaccess');
```

*When I say I have to update permalink structure, I mean I have to go to WP Dashboard > Settings > Permalinks and have to click 'Save'*

Comment: Where are you using this code? Plugin or theme?

Comment: @brasofilo In plugin.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `flush_rules()` WP function to refresh the rewrite rule cache programatically (which also updates the .htacccess), without going to Settings -> Permalinks and having to click save.

Please, note that it is not recommended to call this function on each page load, because it can greatly reduce performance. Instead, make sure that it is called only when necessary.

For more information about it, you can refer to this codex link: http://codex.wordpress.org/Rewrite_API/flush_rules

**EDIT** Use the following code to flush the rules on plugin activation.

```
// calling this function will make flush_rules to be called at the end of the PHP execution
function myplugin_enable_flush_rules() {

    global $wp_rewrite;

    // flush the rewrite rules
    $wp_rewrite->flush_rules();

}

// on plugin activation, call the function that will make flush_rules to be called at the end of the PHP execution
register_activation_hook( __FILE__, 'myplugin_enable_flush_rules' );
```

Comment: Where should I put flush_rules()? I am trying to add above function in plugin. I mean a plugin which will enable GZIP compression by adding above contents in .htaccess.

Comment: Usually, plugins do that on activation. I've posted a piece of code in my above answer with an example way of doing that.

Comment: I have added your code exactly below my function, Deactivate and Reactivated the plugin again but unfortunately it's not adding my code in .htaccess. Am I doing anything wrong?

Comment: I think i've understood what's the situation. I've edited the code in my response above - please have a try with it.

Comment: A side note: please consider that the AddOutputFilterByType is deprecated, and it might not work on all servers, which would make your plugin cause server errors.

Comment: Brilliant! One more question, can you just guide me how can I roll-back (remove) this rewrite rules on plugin deactivation? What I want is to add the above rewrite rules on plugin activation and removal (roll-back) rewrite rules on deactivation.

Comment: The solution for removing the code from .htaccess is totally different. So you might want to post a new question on Stack Overflow, so more people will see it and will try to help you.

Comment: I am going to ask a new question for removing the code from .htaccess. However I have one question with in the same topic. The above function adds rewrite rules with in default WordPress rules lies between `# BEGIN WordPress` and `# END WordPress`. What could I do to add it separately (at the bottom of .htaccess ?)

Comment: Adding rules to .htaccess manually, or removing them manually, would require a custom, totally different solution than the one that i showed you here. You can add this question to your new question that you're going to ask, as the two questions are related.

Comment: I have posted another question  :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25464243/edit-htaccess-on-plugin-deactivate